# I am asked to move to another position. Is it OK for me to ask for a raise?

Tags: salary, raise

## About me

I am a new employee and also fresh on the job market. I graduated 3 months ago. Did really good in college, found myself a first job (as a software developer) 2 months ago without any problems. An internship, actually, but I was offered a job really quickly and agreed to that. This is my first real job (aside from a few internships during college).

## The situation

I have an idea about the entry level salary in my city for a developer, but because my company is working in a specific, niche technology, they offered me about 30% less (because of my minor experience) and offered a fairly good raise every 2-3 months. I agreed.

Now, the company I'm working for is doing a lot of work for another company in another city, and I was asked to go there for a month  for an induction training. I agreed. I was receiving a very positive feedback during the training.

During my last week there I had an unexpected internal interview - as it turned out, they want me to switch to another role within the company. They later told me they interviewed about 10 people and I was the best... The point is, that new role is something I have no major experience in, and also it is more demanding and there is a lot of pressure and stress while working there. So, because I am comfortable in my current role (and it is a long-term decision), I said no, and they said: no problem. And I was relieved, to be honest. Also, they didn't mention any raise for me.

A couple of days later, they offer me the same thing again and here I am...

## The dillema

Would it be ok for me to agree to move to that role, but ask for a raise? I mean, they want me to take a more stressful job, and apparently I did really good during the induction and interview. The duties of new position extend my current duties (not only programming, but also other things). So I feel like I could learn a lot of stuff there, too. On the other hand, it's something different than I initially agreed to, so re-negotiating seems like a logical move. Also, I just feel that the money I'm currently making is to little, considering my new (if I agree) responsibilities.

Even though they are telling me there is no pressure for me to work in that position, I can really feel that they want me to. And I don't know if me saying "no" again wouldn't be frowned upon. 
The situation is further complicated by the fact that I am employed in my company (A), but will be working remotely almost only for the other company (B). I don't know exactly how it works, but probably cannot negotiate my salary directly with my boss, because he must negotiate it with people from company B.

Any advice? Please understand that this is my first job and I really don't know how I should feel about it.

**EDIT**. I should have also mentioned that this time they proposed that I can spend 2-3 days in the new role as some sort of "trial" before saying my final word. Just to see what the work will be there. Because I won't be able to revert if I say yes.

**EDIT2** I will obviously be trying the new role before saying my final word. That will give me more time and insight on what will I be doing. From what I know now, it involves not only programming, but also contact with the clients and a few more things. Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Comment: I'm voting to close because your post is too long and your question has no real useful answers. Consider rewriting this "*[How] can I negotiate a raise when I'm promoted internally?*" or something similar and cutting out a lot of the background info.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the role they are proposing you involves more responsibility and more stress, then it sounds reasonable to consider asking for a raise, especially if your interview went well and you feel like they specifically want you for the job. I believe asking for a raise is reasonable here. That said, it doesn't mean you'll get it : it is possible (although not too likely) that hiring you at your current rate, then proposing you to switch was the plan all along. They might also not be able to give you a raise, for various reasons, but that doesn't mean you should not ask, the only thing you should worry about is "is it reasonable to ask for a raise" and I believe the answer is yes.

About saying "no" a second time : making the same offer a couple of days later, without changing anything to it, nor to your own current situation, and expecting a different answer is not reasonable, so I wouldn't worry about appearing as rude or ungrateful if declining the first offer went fine. If you decline a second time, and you feel like you are perceived as rude for it, that might be a red flag.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. They actually told me that they specifically want me for the job (they think I would fit in great). 
As for making the "same" offer, this time they proposed that I can spend 2-3 days as some sort of "trial" before saying my final word. Just to see what the work will be there.

Comment: In that case, trying the new role would give you more weight if you intend to justify the hypothetical raise by the increased amount of stress/responsibility. It may sound more credible if you actually tried it beforehand, even if a few days probably are not enough to get the hang of it.

Comment: I will be taking the trial, see my 2nd edit.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood from this is you are working under company A's name at company B. Company B hired you in (through company A) for a certain position and now want want you to take on a different role.

If you are only being paid by company A then take it up with them.

If company B is paying you then I would politely ask about a raise if there is more responsibilities and stress to this new role/position.
Furthermore you have a right to say "no" (especially if it is the same offer).

P.S. Seriously check with company A, seeing as you technically work for them.

Comment: Yes, I work for company A and only signed contract with them. I will be asking them if me moving to another role involves signing additional documents and if it is possible for me to get a raise, too.

Comment: @AbstractObject I saw the edit, if I were you I would take the trial and take time to think about it, the more time the better right? Your situation seems similar to my brother's who was offered a different position at a company he was sent to (it would mean he would have to stop working at the company that sent him there), he didn't accept. Shortly after that company went down anyway.

Comment: I will be taking the trial, see my 2nd edit.

Comment: @AbstractObject awesome, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Salary is usually a function of two inputs :

- Work (value you create, work conditions, required dedication ...)
- Capita (experience, degree ...)

Considering the fact that the offered job requires more of you ("more work"), it's definitely possible to discuss of the salary you may obtain.

In my opinion, neither you may nor you should, you must discuss about it.

A convenient way to do that is not to ask directly for a raise but to ask about your perspectives, arguing this will allow you to do a "P&L" in order to take a decision.

Comment: Exactly. I am quite happy with my current role and money. The new role  involves more pressure etc. - I'm OK with that, I think it might be very interesting, but I don't see why would I take the risk without any benefits. And I don't know if they expect me to do it.